# How to speed up Liferay FacetedSearch?

Tags: solr, liferay, liferay-6

I have been looking into our liferay search because search requests (result were 27 documents) takes pretty long (around 5 seconds) to be displayed.

The first thing I noticed was that the search with the FacetedSearcher takes around 2,5 seconds and that´s also my question:

**Is there a way to speed up this faceted search? Anything we can do to make the search faster ?**

Any help is welcome !!

best regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble with Liferay search performance you should plug Liferay with SolR. SolR is much more performant than lucene.

Take a look at: https://www.liferay.com/fr/marketplace/-/mp/application/36322550 and https://www.liferay.com/fr/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrate+Solr+with+Liferay+portal

**Update**

Sorry I didn't see the "solr" tag. So you already used SolR with Liferay ?

If yes could you give us your solr configuration (1 Solr for reading and 1 SolR for indexing ? 1 SolR for all ? etc)